# How to remove duplicate record from results doing left join in sql

Tags: sql, duplicates, left-join, inner-join

I have three tables `User`, `Enquiry` and `Activity`. When I do an `INNER` and `LEFT JOIN`, I am getting duplicate records because of `NULL` values.

**User**:

```
User_id | user_firstName | user_lastName
--------+----------------+--------------
1       | Joe            | Smith 
2       | John           | Doe
3       | Robert         | Smith
```

**Enquiry**:

```
EnquiryID  | CreatedBy|  
-----------+------------
1          |     1          
2          |     1
```

**Activity**:

```
ActivityID | CreatedBy| AssignedBy| AssignedTO
-----------+----------+-----------+----------- 
1          |     1    |    null   |  null      
2          |     1    |      2    |   3
```

Expected output of all three combining result is

```
Enquiry ID |  CreatedBy | AssignedBy | AssignedTO 
-----------+------------+------------+------------
1          |     Joe    |    null    |  null     
2          |     Joe    |      John  |   Rober
```

SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    E.EnquirdID AS Enquiry,
    U.FirstName AS CreatedBy,
    U1.FirstName AS AssignedBy,
    U2.FirstName AS AssignedTo
FROM 
    Enquiry E 
INNER JOIN 
    User U ON E.UserID = U.UserID 
INNER JOIN 
    Activity A ON E.Enquiry = A.EnquiryID
LEFT JOIN 
    User U1 ON A.AssignedBy = U1.UserID 
LEFT JOIN 
    User U2 ON A.AssignedTo = U2.UserID
```

I am getting duplicate `Enquiry` records from this query, even though I'm using `DISTINCT` for `EnquiryID`

END RESULT: my plan is to use the SQL to select the data and display it in PHP on a website. It's an enquiry management website. I want to be able to have PHP pull the variables from SQL so I can use them however I feel fit.

Comment: Your query is full of errors on columns and table names. How do you get any results?

Comment: Your query is working as you expect it to. The only thing is that the columns in the query don't match those in the tables.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Read what DISTINCT does in the manual. Rows that have NULL in the same place differ in standard SQL. Please explain what you want the result to look like in terms of the input. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear & complete. Otherwise you are expecting us to guess from one tiny example & some wrong code.  PS Re the [mcve] you should give: What is your DBMS? Where in your query's logical evaluation do you first get something that you don't expect?

Answer (score 0):

The query seems to work as expected. I just fixed some syntax and column names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EnquiryID as Enquiry, U.user_FirstName as CreatedBY ,U1.user_FirstName as AssignedBY  , U2.user_FirstName as AssignedTO 
FROM Enquiry E inner join [User] U on E.createdby = U.User_ID 
               inner join Activity A on E.EnquiryID = A.createdby
               Left Join [User] U1  on A.AssignedBY = U1.User_ID 
               Left Join [User] U2 on  A.AssignedTO = U2.User_ID
```